# Using a curl request with Angular $http

Tags: angularjs, http, curl

I'm trying to use this api request in my angular application

```
    curl https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/articles.json \
    -v -u {email_address}:{password}
```

This does work in terminal but I honestly just don't know how to format that for the $http service in angular. Still new. Thank you for any help!

Edit: It is a GET request

Comment: Do you know what kind of authentication is performed while requesting this URL with curl?

Comment: I think they can use the email:password approach, API Token, or Oauth Token.

https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction#security-and-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of authentication that you have or want to perform to access this API.
The simplest is probably BASIC authentication.

For a BASIC authentication, as per [rfc2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), you have to provide a valid BASIC authorization header in your request.

This can be performed by setting this header once for all like this with AngularJS:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + basic-credentials;
```

Where *basic-credentials* is the base64 encoded *user:password* string.

So subsequent requests will use this header and will be authorized by this API.

If you haven't already read it, you can take a look at AngularJS $http [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) which describes how to set HTTP headers and use the $http service. 
It also provides an example of BASIC authentication.